# Redis cache not being cleared despite setting TTL

Tags: redis, spring-cache, spring-data-redis, redis-cache

I want the data stored in redis cache to be cleared from the cache automatically after a given period, without calling the delete method on it. In this POC, I am setting the TTL as 60 seconds. I have tried setting it in Cache manager using the API setDefaultExpiration, setExpires and in the RedisTemplate using the API expire. None of the solutions have worked for me so far.

```
@Configuration
public class RedisServerConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {
    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        return redisTemplate;
    }
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate) {
        RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate);
        redisCacheManager.setUsePrefix(true);
        redisCacheManager.setCacheNames(cacheNames);
        redisCacheManager.setTransactionAware(true);
        redisCacheManager.setLoadRemoteCachesOnStartup(true);

        // Using setDefaultExpiration
        //redisCacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(60);

        // Using setExpires
        //Map<String, Long> expires = new HashMap<>();
        //cacheNames.stream().forEach(name->expires.put(name, 60L));
        //redisCacheManager.setExpires(expires);
        return redisCacheManager;
    }
    @Bean
    public RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
        poolConfig.setMaxTotal(maxTotal);
        poolConfig.setMaxIdle(maxIdle);
        poolConfig.setMinIdle(minIdle);
        poolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        poolConfig.setTestOnReturn(true);
        poolConfig.setTestWhileIdle(true);
        poolConfig.setMaxWaitMillis(secondsToWait);
        JedisConnectionFactory factory = new JedisConnectionFactory(sentinelConfig(), poolConfig);
        factory.setUsePool(true);
        factory.setPassword(redisPassword);
        factory.setPort(redisPort);

        return factory;
    }
}
```

In the redis repository used,

```
@Repository
public class RedisRepository {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RedisRepositoryImpl.class);
    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate;
    public void saveSharedSecret(String customerNumber, String sharedSecret) {
        redisTemplate.opsForHash().put(MfaConstants.REDIS_SHAREDSECRET_REGION, myKey, myValue);
        redisTemplate.expire(myKey, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        // The timeOut obtained here is zero
        logger.info("myKey: [{}], timeOut: [{}]", myKey, redisTemplate.getExpire(myKey, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    }
}
```

Kindly point me in the right direction. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code:

```
redisTemplate.opsForHash().put(MfaConstants.REDIS_SHAREDSECRET_REGION, myKey, myValue);
redisTemplate.expire(myKey, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

So basically you want to expire a key inside a hash. But unfortunately, it's cannot be done using standard redis command.

[Reference](https://redislabs.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/chapter-3-commands-in-redis/3-7-other-commands/3-7-3-expiring-keys/)

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I did not understand what you are trying to tell me.

Comment: You're trying to expire a key inside a hash, it cannot be done: `redisTemplate.expire(myKey, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);`

Comment: Would it be possible for you to show a valid use case? Perhaps the documentation, any blog or some example that you know?

Comment: Are you trying to tell me that you can set the expiry time for the cache being accessed by the redis template but not the hash stored?

Comment: You can expire the whole key, not individual items inside a `hash` or `zset`. You're trying to expire a key in the hash, it will not work. Is it clear?

Comment: Yes, it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to expire a cache after some time, [usually the people use](https://redislabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Spring-Session-Redis-Why-How-and-Production-Pitfalls.pdf) the `Scheduled` with `CacheEvict`. So, the scheduler run after some time and call the cache evict.

For example:

```
@Cacheable(value = "parameters-all")
public List<ParametroResponse> getAll() {
    return repository.findAll();
}

@CacheEvict(allEntries = true, cacheNames = { "parameters-all" })
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${spring.cache.redis.ttl}")
public void cacheEvict() {
    log.info("parameters-all cache evicted");
}
```

Comment: For the benefit of those using this solution, you can refer this [link](https://redislabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Spring-Session-Redis-Why-How-and-Production-Pitfalls.pdf) for description. If you can find the official documentation, kindly add the link for further reading/ reference.

Comment: @fullStack, thank you for the feedback. I added the link.